# Can "lie" be a transitive verb?

Tags: verbs

Can the verb "lie" be a transitive when it's used in the sense of "to occupy a certain relative place"?

My son's math book had the following task:

> If the maximum point of y = ax² + bx + 1 is (3 , 4) , which quadrant lies (a , b)?

I was a bit puzzled by this usage of "lie" here. Shouldn't it be rather used with preposition "at"? Like here:

> If the maximum point of y = ax² + bx + 1 is (3 , 4) , which quadrant lies **at** (a , b)?

Or is it like "to lie at a point" and "to lie a point" are two different phrases with two different meanings?

Comment: It's a mistake. They've missed out "in": _in which quadrant lies (a,b)._

Comment: and "in which quadrant does (a, b) lie?" would be significantly clearer, IMO

Comment: What @DavidSiegel said. The point (a,b) ***lies in*** some quadrant. It makes no sense to say the quadrant lies in the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the *in*, as @Colin Fine has commented.

> If the maximum point of y = ax² + bx + 1 is (3 , 4), [in] which quadrant lies (a , b)?

*lie* in this case is intransitive, as explained below.

> B1 [ I + adv/prep, L ] present participle lying | past tense lay | past participle lain
> If something lies in a particular place, position, or direction, it is in that place, position, or direction.

[reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lie)